# RAID 10 -- still a little unclear on the concept

Tags: freebsd, raid10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the different widely used RAID levels and when should I consider them?](https://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them)

I haven't had any trouble building mental images of the simpler RAID forms, but for some reason my head spins when I try to think about 10.  Let me walk through my conception:

Mirroring is obvious:  N drives, each with a copy of the same data X.  So for N=2, we have D(isc) 0 with Xcopy0, and D1 with Xcopy1.

Striping is obvious:  N drives, each with 1/Nth of each byte.  So for N=2, we have D(isc)0 with Stripe0 having every nybble 0, and D1 with Stripe1 having every nybble 1.

For 10, let's say with 2-bit stripes (i.e., 4 discs), do we need 8 discs, where we mirror D0+D4, D1+D5, D2+D6, and D3+D7, and then stripe D0..D3 (and D4..D7, or does that come for free?).

Or does it work some other way?

Answer (score 4):

Raid 10 is pretty easy. It is a combnination of mirroring (Raid 1) and striping(Raid 0). Instead of striping over single disks you strip over a set of mirrored disks.

```
 Mirror1            Mirror2
+-------+          +-------+
| disk1 | Striping | disk3 |
+-------+ -------- +-------+ -----...
| disk2 |          | disk4 |
+-------+          +-------+
```

This enhances write performance, read performance and redunancy.

You can add as many mirrors as you want to stripe over as many mirror blocks as you want.